# Axis2 error: The addressing-1.5.1.mar module, which is not valid, caused null

Tags: apache-axis

anyone have any idea what could be the cause of the following error and how to resolve it?

org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer 2010-09-23 11:42:40,689 -- ERROR -- The addressing-1.5.1.mar module, which is not valid, caused null

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

```
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.createTempFile(Utils.java:224)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.getURLsForAllJars(Utils.java:165)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.createClassLoader(Utils.java:899)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.setClassLoader(DeploymentFileData.java:115)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:65)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:659)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:251)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:68)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:63)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:147)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:133)

        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)

        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:206)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.TempFileManager.recursiveDelete(TempFileManager.java:138)

        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.TempFileManager.<clinit>(TempFileManager.java:202)

        ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 4):

When this happened to me, I solved the problem by setting java's java.io.tmpdir property to a directory that my Linux user acct could surely write to.  I used "mkdir" while logged into my Linux user account to create the tmpdir before running my application.

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=[writable directory] [other options] [class to run]
```